# How to ping a URL in an Android Service?

Tags: android, url, service, ping

How can I use Android Service to do a ping callback? I need to open a webpage on a button click, but in the background, go ping another URL for stats collection.

Comment: Kotlin implementation supporting API 25+ can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53402128/ping-website-url-before-loading-it-in-webview-in-android-kotlin/53402129

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think if you just want to ping an url, you can use this code :

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://" + params[0]);

    HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android Application:"+Z.APP_VERSION);
    urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
    urlc.setConnectTimeout(1000 * 30); // Timeout is in seconds
    urlc.connect();

    if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
        Main.Log("getResponseCode == 200");
        return new Boolean(true);
    }
} catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And, if you want to have the equivalent of a ping, you can put a System.currentTimeMillis() before and after the call, and calculate the difference.

hopes that helps

code snippet found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-timeouts)

Comment: This has been working fine for me except for Android 4 devices where it always fails. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to move the call off your main thread. Android 4 enforces no network calls on the main thread to prevent ANR issues.

Comment: This will establish a TCP connection with a full 3-way handshake. So the time is nothing like a ping (`ICMP-echo -> ICMP-reply`)

Comment: @NickCampion: for me this code is not working on 4.2.2 device which includes samsung s3 and other , any solution