# how to determine, if an internet connection is currently available and active on an android device?

Tags: java, android, connection

i have this android application that requires to load data from a remote server via the internet. this update-functionaliy obviously requires the device to not only be connected to some kind of network, but also to the internet.

so: is want to schedule the update-service to some date and when it starts, it should determine whether it actually CAN reach the target server or not. therefore, a simple "is the device connected to wifi?" does not suffice, as the device may be connected to a wireless network that does not offer internet access. something like a PING is required...

whats the easiest /  best way to determine, if there is an internet connection is available i.e. server is reachable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448666/how-to-do-a-true-java-ping-from-windows) here on StackOverflow. It should be just what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

```
boolean connected;            
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if(connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || 
                    connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                //we are connected to the internet
                connected = true;
            }
            else
                connected = false;
```

add persmission: `<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Comment: problem: what if my device is connected to some wifi network that does NOT function as an internet gateway?

Answer (score 2):

Just try to connect to your server, and timeout if you haven't started download progress in an acceptable period of time.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786720/android-service-ping-url) is the best answer to problem:

> Device is connected on router but there is no internet gateway active.