# Android force close when no connection

Tags: android

I'm making an aplication that uses internet connection. When i try to download data, but there isn't internet connection application force closes. What do i need to do if I want application not to throw Force close message, but my own message, like "There is no connection..." and then close activity. Thanks!

My logcat output :

```
09-23 14:56:15.411: E/AndroidRuntime(20770): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-23 14:56:15.411: E/AndroidRuntime(20770): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{lt.prasom/lt.prasom.GoodOffers}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-23 14:56:15.411: E/AndroidRuntime(20770):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
09-23 14:56:15.411: E/AndroidRuntime(20770):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
09-23 14:56:15.411: E/AndroidRuntime(20770):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-23 14:56:15.411: E/AndroidRuntime(20770):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
09-23 14:56:15.411: E/AndroidRuntime(20770):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-23 14:56:15.411: E/AndroidRuntime(20770):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-23 14:56:15.411: E/AndroidRuntime(20770):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-23 14:56:15.411: E/AndroidRuntime(20770):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-23 14:56:15.411: E/AndroidRuntime(20770):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-23 14:56:15.411: E/AndroidRuntime(20770):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-23 14:56:15.411: E/AndroidRuntime(20770):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-23 14:56:15.411: E/AndroidRuntime(20770):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-23 14:56:15.411: E/AndroidRuntime(20770): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-23 14:56:15.411: E/AndroidRuntime(20770):    at java.io.StringReader.<init>(StringReader.java:46)
09-23 14:56:15.411: E/AndroidRuntime(20770):    at lt.prasom.functions.XMLParser.getDomElement(XMLParser.java:73)
09-23 14:56:15.411: E/AndroidRuntime(20770):    at lt.prasom.GoodOffers.onCreate(GoodOffers.java:68)
09-23 14:56:15.411: E/AndroidRuntime(20770):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-23 14:56:15.411: E/AndroidRuntime(20770):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
09-23 14:56:15.411: E/AndroidRuntime(20770):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code and the logcat output for the exception

Comment: There are quite a few of those here on SO. [One](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086159/checking-internet-connection-on-android), [Two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154561/how-to-determine-if-an-internet-connection-is-currently-available-and-active-on), [Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753412/android-internet-connectivity-check-problem). Search, and you shall receive. Do that before you ask though.. ;-)

Comment: So what's here?  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.StringReader.<init>(StringReader.java:46)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the below function is used to detect whether device is connected to a network or not.

```
 public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
     ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
     if (connectivity != null) {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
           for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
              if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                 return true;
              }
           }
        }
     }
     return false;
  }
```

You can invoke the function as shown below...

```
if(!isNetworkAvailable(context))
     // Show Toast here...
else
     //perform action ...
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

Before making network connection, check whether the network connection is available or not.
Check this [Detect Internet Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/android-detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available)

If the network connection is available, go ahead and do the processing and if not you can use [Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) message or an [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) to display appropriate message to the user.

If you are planning to close the activity when the internet connection is not available, display a Toast message and call [finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) method.
Something like this:

```
    if (noNetworkAvailable) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No network available",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
```

Note: Since the finish() method will close the activity, Use Toast message instead of AlertDialog because it'll cause "android.view.WindowLeaked" exception.

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest you must add the internet permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```