# start up of eclipse ping UsageServer failed

Tags: android, eclipse

I got problem when i am start my eclipse. that `'Android SDK Ping' has encountered a problem ping UsageServer failed`

I have windows 7 32-bit system and i am using eclipse indigo and android android ADT 20.0.0
If any one can know about the solution than please help me...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5352582/1289716