# how to check device connected wifi internet connection speed?

Tags: android, networking, connection, wifi

I am able to check whether the device is connected to wifi with this.

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, i want to check the wifi connection speed something like Ping. I want to base on this ping number to set some variables. Something like this,

```
public int internetspeed(){
    checking...
    return speed;
}
```

Can someone give me tutorial or example?

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786720/android-service-ping-url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This snippet will do the job for you

```
    WifiManager wifiManager = Context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    if (wifiInfo != null) {
        Integer linkSpeed = wifiInfo.getLinkSpeed(); //measured using WifiInfo.LINK_SPEED_UNITS
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Download file in background and measure data per second.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full class that I use to test connectivity . For the ping matter see my comment .

```
public class InternetCheck {

    Context mContext;
     public InternetCheck(Context mContext){
           this.mContext = mContext;
      }


    // CHECK FOR INTERNET METHOD
    public final boolean isInternetOn() {
        ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        // ARE WE CONNECTED TO THE NET
        if (connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED
                || connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING
                || connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING
                || connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            return true;
        } else if (connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED
                || connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED) {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: The link that you provide is ping a url, but i don't know the device connect to the router ip address, so cannot ping also