# Check if Onion URL is live

Tags: java, android, android-studio, tor

I am making an Android application in Java. There is an onion Url that I want to check is live or not. Basically, Onion Url is mapped to an IP-address, so is there any Java library or API that can assist in determining this check?
Any help in this regard will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by live url?

Comment: @salman it means if you can ping it, it is accessible or not

Comment: you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786720/android-service-ping-url)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a server on which the tor will work and already give from it either the desired status or the page that you need. For the site tor-sites.link we did the proxying of the tor through the tor launched into the container and the express.js server. You can see how it works at [previewer](https://www.tor-sites.link/previewer). Schematically, it looks like this:

1. HTTP request
2. express.js server
3. request to tor
4. returning a response to the client

This way you can get data from the onino site.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:slim

ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install gnupg wget -y && \
  wget --quiet --output-document=- https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | gpg --dearmor > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/google-archive.gpg && \
  sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install google-chrome-stable -y --no-install-recommends && \
  apt-get install tor -y --no-install-recommends && \
  apt-get install torsocks -y --no-install-recommends && \
  apt-get install curl gnupg && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN mkdir src
RUN mkdir tmp
COPY ./src ./src
COPY ./package.json \
     ./ecosystem.config.js \
     ./tsconfig.json \
     ./

RUN npm i -g pm2 npm@9.2.0
RUN yarn && yarn build

RUN rm -rf src


#HEALTHCHECK --start-period=150s --interval=300s --retries=99999 --timeout=120s CMD curl --fail http://localhost:3000/healthcheck || kill 1


EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["pm2-runtime", "start", "ecosystem.config.js"]
```